# Extract information from a GAMLSS object in R

Tags: r

I am using the `lms` function in **gamlss** package for centile regression. After running the `lms()` function a got an object, but I do not know how to display the centile curves.

How to extract the parameters so I can plot the centile curves by my own. I tested the `fitted.plot()` function, but there is an error saying such function do not exist. I have download the 4.2.0 version. I was wondering if someone could help.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about the gamlss package, but simply scanning the documentation for 30 seconds revealed the function `centile.pred` with examples that include plotting centile curves.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation: [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamlss/gamlss.pdf)

As far as I can see the `lms` command is just another version of the `gamlss` fit and those are plotted using the `centiles` command.